# PHP, Login, cookie not found

Tags: php, cookies

I have tried to find a solution here, and worked out some issues with Cookies (such as the problem with setting the cookie before the HTML/Header is created). I have checked my browser, and the cookie is set.

However, when I use code like the following, the value is not showing:

```
echo "cookie name: " . $cookie_name . "<br>";   
   if( isset( $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] ) )
   {
echo "Cookie set: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] . "<br>";
```

The value of the variable $cookie_name is coming from a configuration file that is included, and is returning the correct value. The problem is that isset() is not seeing the cookie. This is probably a very simple issue, but I'm not seeing it. Thanks in advance -- Ken

Per request, adding code to question for readability:

The two variables being used are set to this (at least for now):

```
// for login cookies
$cookie_name = 'GSPCMS_Id';
$cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 10); // 10 days
```

The command that sets the cookie (in the login routine) is:

```
setcookie( $cookie_name, $_SESSION['user_name'], time()+$cookie_time );
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($_COOKIE);` before checking if it is set, just for testing purposes.

Comment: Also, proof that `$cookie_name` is set.

Comment: I am seeing:

  Array ( [PHPSESSID] => nvruifgg3n62srldd2tlgntcm0 )

Comment: The thing is, if I open up options in the browser (Firefox) and search for "localhost", I am finding my cookie listed, and the settings are correct (including expiration date 10 days from now).

Comment: If that is all you're seeing in the array then the name is not set. Can you show the code where you set the name?

Comment: This is the code to set the cookie:
setcookie( $cookie_name, $_SESSION['user_name'], time()+$cookie_time );

The variable $cookie_time is set to:
$cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 10); // 10 days

Comment: Accidentally hit return too soon. Also please note that I stated the cookie is showing up in my browser's options, if I go to examine cookies, it appears, with the correct name, and value, with the timeout set to 10 days from now,

Comment: Correct domain name in the cookie? Seriously, Cookie logic is very reliable in PHP. If your cookie isn't being returned, but the SESSION cookie is, then there is most likely something simple that is wrong with your cookie? Please Add the code to you question :)

Comment: Add the code to your question so it is easier to read. What is `$cookie_name` set to?

Comment: I'm working on this on localhost, so no domain at the moment. The reason I'm here is that the code I'm using is based on code I've found all over the web and I cannot see why it is not finding the cookie.

Comment: I'm running into more and more oddities. It is now telling me that $_SESSION['user_id'] is not correct (it should be, it has worked properly in the past) -- somehow or other I seem to be losing my session now because print_r($SESSION) is returning an empty array. I'm going to take a break ... I need to get my head out of this for a bit.

Comment: My code actually used $_SESSION, sorry ... dumb typo on my part.

Comment: I've commented out the code that tries to read the cookie for now, and am moving on to other things. I thought maybe I had code that was "destroying" the session (session_destroy()) but while I do in case of some errors, it's not being executed in the test code right now (lots of checks). When a form reloads does the session somehow get stomped on? If I call another page the values are there. But in the login page the $_SESSION seems to be gone. I'm really confused by this.

Comment: Having scoured the web and looked at my code, I have given up. I have found code examples for a different approach that I'm going to try (getting the IP address and storing some info in a table ...). I know it's not perfect and with issues with dynamic IP addresses and all it may not work for every situation, but ...